# Ruby on Rails 3.1 : error with "render" in javascrtip (AJAX) from RailsCasts (Search, Sort, Paginate with AJAX)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, render

My code is from: [RailsCasts: Search, Sort, Paginate with AJAX](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?)

I have this error:

```
undefined method render for #<#<Class:0x9e54e54>:0xa860f24>
(in /var/www/final/.../app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb)
```

My application.js.erb:

```
$(function() {
 $("#zoznam_render th a, #zoznam_renders .pagination a").live("click", function() {
    $("#zoznam_render").html("**<%=j render 'zoznam' %>**");
    return false;
  }); });
```

In index.html.erb render 'zoznam'(_zoznam.html.erb) is OK. "zoznam/index" is list of my products with custom sql select. It´s all OK but "bold" script is not good. '

Answer (score 0):

from **TheCompWiz**:
[original forum](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?view=comments#comment_154161)
Ok... I think I found a fix for rails 3.1. The trick is to keep from using assets. You need the page to be rendered. This may seem hack-ish... I agree... but it does work. This can probably be better refined in the future.

What you need to do, is add an entry in the routes file before the "resources" for products like so:

> match "/products/index.js", :controller => 'products', :action =>
> 'index', :format => :js

and proceed as normal. What this does in essence is get Rails to skip using the brand-new asset manager system... and go back to the old-fashioned rendering setup. This is probably a good thing as the index.js is rendered per-request and won't be concat'd together with the other javascript and not minified.

//maybe good answer...